# use global string as default param with move semantic

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

i want to reuse a global string, and avoid copy ctor. and usually used as a default param in some function, my code like below.

i avoid to overload constructor because c++ not support constructor called in constructor.

and i know if i use "const char* aaa" instead of using "const std::string aaa", 
it will also fine, but copy cannot avoid..

i use variable not macro, because of it's multiline format ugly and code expand reason

so how should be the perfect solution here?

```
const std::string aaa = R"(a long code string [xxx] )";

class A {
public:
    A(const std::string &&a = aaa) { std::cout<< a; }
};

A a;
A aa("bb");
```

then i will get the error

```
error: rvalue reference to type 'const basic_string<[3 * ...]>' cannot bind to lvalue of type 'const basic_string<[3 * ...]>'
    A(const std::string &&a = aaa) { std::cout<< a; }
```

Comment: Are you going to modify this string? If not, then use `const char*`. You can't move from a `const` thing because moving may change that thing.

Comment: what do you mean about moving may change that thing? is using std::move(aaa) as default param right?

Comment: `aaa` is `const`. You can't move anything from it. So you can't have move semantics. So your question is moot.

Comment: Just to add to what juanchopanza has already said, std::move is basically used to cast a lvalue to rvalue so that someone can take control of the resources within the rvalue leaving the original object that was moved from in a state where it can either be destroyed or assigned to. To leave it in a state where it can be safely destroyed, you will need to be able to change it. a 'const' object can't be changed and hence you can't use it as a parameter to a move constructor.

Comment: @user3493289 maybe my question not clear, why not reference collapsing rule happen here?

Comment: Reference collapsing happens only in the case of typedefs or aliases and also only for rvalue parameters in function templates both of which are not present in the code above